# Computing matrices to a power of $6$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Compute
$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{3} & -1 \\ 1 & \sqrt{3} \end{pmatrix}^6.$

How would I solve this question. I found out that it's square would be $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2\sqrt{3} \\ 2\sqrt{3} & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$ What next? Is there any easier way?

Comment: Notice that you are calculating $(2R_{\pi/6})^6$, where $R_{\theta}$ is the [*rotation matrix*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{1}$

we seek $A^6$, where

$A = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{3} & -1 \\ 1 & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} = \sqrt{3} I + J; \tag{2}$

we note that we may write $A$ as

$A = 2(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} I + \dfrac{1}{2}J); \tag{3}$

noting further that

$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos \dfrac{\pi}{6}, \tag{4}$

$\dfrac{1}{2} = \sin \dfrac{\pi}{6}, \tag{5}$

we see we may write

$A = 2(\cos \dfrac{\pi}{6} I + \sin \dfrac{\pi}{6} J); \tag{6}$

next, we observe that

$J^2 = - I; \tag{7}$

from (7) we may deduce that matrices of the general form $(\cos \theta) I + (\sin \theta) J$ satisfy a variant of de Moivre's formula;

$((\cos \theta) I + (\sin \theta) J)^n = (\cos n\theta) I + (\sin n\theta) J; \tag{8}$

(8) is, like its scalar equivalent, easy to prove by induction; since the proof is virtually identical to that for the scalar version, we won't repeat it here, but see
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula.  With the aid of (7), we compute

$A^6 = 2^6(\cos \dfrac{\pi}{6} I +  \sin \dfrac{\pi}{6} J)^6 = 64(\cos \pi I + \sin \pi J) = -64I. \tag{9}$

Comment: *Fiat Lux!!* ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  Indeed, ***Fiat Lux!!!***  May these forbidden words be ever in our hearts and minds!  Thanks, and Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you had multiplied one more time:
$$
             A^{3} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -8 \\ 8 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$
Then $A^{6}=A^{3}A^{3}=-64I$.

Comment: Note that $\det(A) = 4$ so $\det(A^3) = (\det(A))^3 = 4^3 = 64$; but you are showing $\det(A^3) = -64$; wassup with that?  Cheers!

Comment: That should be $A^{3} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -8 \\ 8 & 0\end{array}\right)$, so $A^6=-64I$.

Comment: @r.e.s.:  *veritas*; see my answer! Cheers!

Comment: @r.e.s. and and RobertLewis. Thanks for catching the negative.

Comment: @TrialAndError:  glad to help out!